# Handling route changes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm struggling to handle the back button and ask confirmation to the user, if app state is dirty. Closing tab and reload is already handled via the `onbeforeunload` hook.

I've played with `$routeChangeStart`, `$beforeRouteChange`, etc. but can't handle it correctly.
With `$routeChangeStart`, the route is effectively changed before my callback is called.

What is the correct way to handle this situation?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe $locationChangeStart fires when you would like it to.

Comment: This event is the good one. Unfortunately, there is a bug, never triggered by back button, which have just been fixed in Angular: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2206

Answer (score 2):

you could use:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
   //broadcasted before a route change
   // do something here
});
```

See more of it on : [$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route)

Comment: My apologize, I'm already using $routeChangeStart, but my route is effectively changed (in the URL bar) before I handled it.

Comment: I think there's been a misunderstanding; the URL bar changed because *that's* that the routing engine is responding to. Of course it already changed! How else would it know what route to hit? :-) But you still have the option of not handling the route, which is what the `$routeChangeStart` is for. I think this is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a model of the dirty state in a parent controller, common to all views?  An alert/confirm appears if a dirty state is detected by any view's controller, with a "Cancel" button that resets $location.path(...) to the dirty page.